# managing opengraph and meta properties with backbone (or any JS MVC framework)

Tags: backbone.js, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I have a backbone app (a blog) displaying different articles we can share on many platforms.

I try to use open graph with google and facebook, i update the properties in the router just before rendering the view.

But the thing is, when the **scraper** reach the app, it doesn't get the meta properties, i don't know if it doesn't execute javascript or if it's too fast, but if i set up some default meta properties directly in my single page it works.

However i need to update the meta properties about the url (each article has their own meta properties).

So, is it possible to use open graph with backbone.js ?

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the problem and it seems Facebook is not running javascript in their end. There is no way, but creating separate page in your server for stuff you want to share on Facebook and include all meta tags statically in those pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are services that will render javascript generated page for SEO purposes. Check out https://prerender.io

An alternative is to have your server populate the `<meta>` tags before the page is served.